# C++ Struct prototyping in separate header file

Tags: c++, c, struct, makefile

I am having trouble understanding [an answer I saw in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15327656/3550237).  It said that it is good practice to define a struct in a separate .h file so it can be used in other files.  I think that is great and it solves my current dilemma, however I have a question about compilation and makefiles.  I am only familiar with having header files that are associated with .cpp files at the moment.

Can someone explain how that implementation would look when I have a .h and no .cpp? Do I need an implementation file as well? Also, how do I link the header in a makefile? Currently I only know how to compile a .cpp & header into a .o file and link them.

Thanks, and sorry for taking us back to c++ kindergarten.  This is a new revelation and seems like a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept is that you *define* the struct/class in a `.h` header, so that you can *use* it in multiple `.cpp` files. Whenever you need `struct foo` defined in `foo.h`, you `#include "foo.h"`. You don't need to directly compile the header file, it will be pulled in by whichever source file uses it. Therefore you don't need a make target for `.h` in normal circumstances.

If the definition in the header is never used, it won't be pulled in and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, I learn something new from you guys everyday!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a matching source file (.c or .cpp) for every header .h file.

Having header files without corresponding source files is just fine.

When you #include some header file, you can think of it as a kind of *"copy and paste"* operation: the preprocessor copies the content of the header file, and pastes it in the point of inclusion.
(Well, there are some details to consider here, for example the presence of a `#pragma once` directive or some `#ifdef` inclusion guard can prevent *multiple inclusions* of the same header file in a given project.)

The C and C++ compilers will then process the whole "compilation unit", i.e. the current source file with all the included headers.

Comment: The distinction between header file and compilation unit is also important from another perspective: The compilation unit (.cpp + .h) gets compiled to machine code that is being shipped, i.e., the program or the library. In order to use a library's API, you need the (clear-text) header file, plus, of course, the library itself. However, the source code contained in the .cpp files does not need to be shipped.